# Subir imagenes pesadas al servidor con DropZone y laravel

Tags: laravel-5, dropzone

hola amigos estoy trabajando con Larvel 5.5 y Dropzone , el problema es el siguiente, DropZone no me permite subir imágenes mayores a 2MB, procedo a  cambiar la propiedad **maxFilesize:100** pero no me funciona,

adjunto imágenes del código

View
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

codigo en el controlador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta revisar la configuracion de tu php.ini y tu servidor (apache, nginx, etc) y revisa la configuracion de post_max_size y upload_max_filesize

Comment: Gracias amigo, específicamente  esa era la solución,

Comment: Que versión de drop zone usas ?

Comment: @GerardoLopezDueñas Deberías poner eso como respuesta (incluyendo algo más de detalle como ¿qué valores deberían tener o esperarías que tuviesen y por qué?)

Answer (score -1):

La limitante en este caso la esta definiendo el archivo de configuración de PHP: php.ini, debe editarlo y cambiar las siguientes variables:
1) nano /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
2) Cambiar: 
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M